# Ckeditor not working in vue js with laravel 5.5

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, vue.js, ckeditor

I have tried with Ckeditor js and also with vue package.

I dont know where to initialize CKeditor in vue js

Answer (score 2):

Multiple results can be found with a search:

- [dangvanthanh/vue-ckeditor2](https://github.com/dangvanthanh/vue-ckeditor2): a ready-to-use component with an installation [example](https://github.com/dangvanthanh/vue-ckeditor2/wiki/Getting-Started)
- On [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104438/use-ckeditor-instance-in-vue-js) @bflydesign asked how to use the CKEditor with vue.js - 2 years ago
- Christopher Wilson implemented a working example on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/CSWApps/pen/vmbNVp)

```html
<p data-height="265" data-theme-id="0" data-slug-hash="vmbNVp" data-default-tab="js,result" data-user="CSWApps" data-embed-version="2" data-pen-title="CKEditor v4 & Vue.js v2" class="codepen">See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/CSWApps/pen/vmbNVp/">CKEditor v4 & Vue.js v2</a> by Christophor Wilson (<a href="https://codepen.io/CSWApps">@CSWApps</a>) on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</p>
<script async src="https://production-assets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```